# Generics and Constraints (`Instance method '...' requires that 'T' conform to 'Decodable'`)

Tags: swift, generics, codable, decodable, generic-constraints

I have a generic struct allowing different types to be used. I do not want to constrain the whole struct to only Decodable items.

What is the best way to fix the following error, where I try to only execute some code if T conforms to Decodable:
`Instance method '...' requires that 'T' conform to 'Decodable'`

```
struct Something<T> {
    ...

    func item<T>(from data: Data) -> T? where T: Decodable {
        try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
    
    func getter() -> T {
        let value = ...
        
        if let value = value as? T { return value } // something simple like string
        if let data = value as? Data, T.self is Decodable { // something complex
            return item(from: data) ?? defaultValue // error is thrown here
        }
        
        return defaultValue
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm checking the conformance with the if-clause, but that isn't enough to access the constrained method? :/

Answer (score 4):

It makes no sense to me that T only needs to conform to `Decodable` in some part but not others. I would rewrite the struct as

```
struct Something<T: Decodable> {

    func item(from data: Data) -> T?  {
        try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
    }

    func getter() -> T {
        let value = ...
     
        if let data = value as? Data
            return item(from: data) ?? defaultvalue
        }

        return defaultvalue
    }
}
```

Comment: Because there might be types which do not conform to Decodable? And for those other types I still would like to use the same struct to handle it.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to mix it like that, maybe have T not conform to Decodable and have a separate Factory class (or factory methods) that can create `Something` objects from different types of input like json data. I think your `getter` function will soon become a giant mess if you need to support different conversion of  different types to T. You want to have that outside of your class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should constrain T to Decodable when you define the struct. Second, you must not define T as a generic parameter of the functions internally as it will not be treated as the same T the struct conforms to by the compiler. Instead it will be treated as a new and different generic type constraint (that you just happened to give the same name). Doing it like this is enough:

```swift
struct Something<T: Decodable> {
  
  var defaultValue: T
  var data: Data
  
  func item(from data: Data) -> T? {
    try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
  }
  
  func getter() -> T {
    item(from: data) ?? defaultValue
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension to define the more constrained method:

```
struct Something<T> {
   var defaultValue: T

   func getter() -> T {
      return defaultValue
   }
}

extension Something where T: Decodable {
   func getter() -> T {

      // I'm assuming here that you have a property data: Data
      try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) ?? defaultValue
   }
}
```

It's not entirely clear how you're going to use this type in a meaningful way. The way your code is constructed, `value` is `Any` type. Is this what you meant? (I'm guessing, not)

Somewhere, you'd need to make a concrete version of `Something` - i.e. it would be `Something<Int>` or `Something<String>` or `Something<SomeDecodableType>` - at that point `T` will be that concrete type, and as you can see, there's nothing common between the various versions of `T`, except `Any`.

So figure out what parts of `Something` truly are common.